# Redefine standard textstyles in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, text-styling

Is it possible to redefine standard text styles: `UIFontTextStyleBody`, `UIFontTextStyleHeadline`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it's not. 
As I understand it's similar to the custom CSS sheet in Safari — user select fonts he like, and then he see those fonts in apps, that support dynamic fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `UIAppereance` can be to help? It allows you to set fonts and styles for any kind of view/element in any controller.